# Why is a black & white movie shown in middle of the movie?

Tags: plot-explanation, winters-bone

In [Winter's Bone](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1399683/), some black & white movie is shown in the middle of the movie:

[image]

What for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the black and white scene in the middle of the movie is a [dream sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_sequence), which are often used in movies as a convenient way for the storyteller to reveal something about a character's thought process, or something in a character's past.

The reason behind the dream sequence is hypothesised in [this article](http://www.cinemablend.com/reviews/Winter-Bone-4792.html):

> As Ree attempts to solve her family’s financial problems, we learn
>   there’s a solution. She could simply sell the timberland behind her
>   home to pay the bills. After an odd, completely out of place dream
>   sequence involving burning forests, the rise of civilization, and some
>   cute squirrels, Ree decides she cannot sell the timber.

It seems that the dream sequence is used to highlight the importance of the timberland to Ree, and provide justification as to why she can't sell it.

The dream sequence itself can be viewed [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8arLi2xjaI).